# ROS Answers SE migration: navigation

Tags: navigation, kinect, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone. i am working on a robot for autonomous navigation. Currently i am able to move my robot via joy stick and also to map area using rtabmap and kinect. now i want to move my robot in a direction or position given in the map.i have ROS indego. how should i proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241067/navigation/) by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have you checked out the [navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials)?
This should answer your question.

(At the time of this writing, the tutorials page is quite a mess. I'll clean that up later on...)
Of special interest for you are the following tutorials:
1, 4, 6, and 10-13

**EDIT** just fixed the wiki page, all clean now again...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1